sliding-tile problem using hill climbing algorithm
I am trying to solve the 8 puzzle or sliding tile problem using Hill-Climbing algorithm in python. I Wrote the code to print each intermediate step until goal node is reached but no output is shown by the interpreter. Please review my code and tell me about the errors in the code and solution to them.
Hi there, I am trying to solve the 8 puzzle or sliding tile problem using Hill-Climbing algorithm in python. I Wrote the code to print each intermediate step until goal node is reached but no output is shown by the interpreter. Please tell me about the errors in the code and solution to them.
from copy import deepcopy

class State:
    def __init__(self, state, parent):
        goal_state = [[1, 2, 3], [8, 0, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
        self.parent = parent
        self.state = state
        self.cost = self.calculate_cost(goal_state)

    def calculate_cost(self, goal_state):

        cost = 0

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.state[i][j] != goal_state[i][j]:
                    cost += 1

        return cost


    def generate_neighbors(self):
        neighbors = []

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.state[i][j] == 0:

                    if i >= 0 and i != 2:   #move down
                        new_state = deepcopy(self.state)
                        new_state[i][j], new_state[i+1][j] = new_state[i+1][j], new_state[i][j]
                        neighbors.append(State(new_state, self))

                    if i <=2 and i != 0:    #move up
                        new_state = deepcopy(self.state)
                        new_state[i][j], new_state[i-1][j] = new_state[i-1][j], new_state[i][j]
                        neighbors.append(State(new_state, self))

                    if j >= 0 and j != 2: # move right
                        new_state = deepcopy(self.state)
                        new_state[i][j], new_state[i][j+1] = new_state[i][j+1], new_state[i][j]
                        neighbors.append(State(new_state, self))

                    if j <= 2 and j != 0:   # move left
                        new_state = deepcopy(self.state)
                        new_state[i][j], new_state[i][j-1] = new_state[i][j-1], new_state[i][j]
                        neighbors.append(State(new_state, self))


        return neighbors

def hill_climbing(initial_state):

    current_state = State(initial_state, None)

    while current_state.cost > 0:

        neighbors = current_state.generate_neighbors()

        best_neighbor = min(neighbors, key = lambda state: state.cost)

        if current_state.cost > best_neighbor.cost:
            current_state = best_neighbor

    path = []
    while current_state is not None:
        path.append(current_state.state)
        current_state = current_state.parent

    return path[::-1]






initial_state = [[2, 0, 3], [1, 8, 4], [7, 6, 5]]

path = hill_climbing(initial_state)

# Print the solution path
for state in path:
    print(state)


I do now know how it should work, but the problem is that, your best_neighbor.cost will be constantly 4 so the while current_state.cost > 0 is acting as an infinite loop, as the value of the current_state.costs depends on best_neighbor.cost. I will never reach the print() at the end. I suggest you to put print in the while loops or even better if you use the debugger.

@Shrey, you received answers below. Any feedback on them? Did you find your answer?

I am not sure, but maybe the problem is caused by the if statement in your generate_neighbors function.
Try to change:
if self.state[i][j] == 0 to if self.state[i][j] != 0

i don't think so because if self.state[i][j] is looking for the empty tile

I still do not know the algorithm, but in that case as you are using the [[2, 0, 3], [1, 8, 4], [7, 6, 5]] as an init state, then okay, it will find zero at (0,1). It will generate neighbors with cost 5 (from move down), cost 4 (from move right), cost 5 (from move left). Then you take the lowest cost which is 4, but it is till higher than the current state cost, so the same will happen again and again...

if move down from initial state I'll get the with cost 3, 4(from left), 5(from right)

Check the result, it will return 5 (from down), 4 (from right), 5 (from, left)

Sorry, I checked it again. You are right, in the first iteration it will be 3 (down), 5 (right), 3 (left), and the problem starts from the second iteration, when it will be 5 (down), 4 (up), 5 (right), 4 (left), and none of them will less than 3 (from the previous choosen neighbor's cost), so from that point it will stack in an infinite loop.

There are a few issues:

When the condition in if current_state.cost > best_neighbor.cost: is not true, the next iteration of the loop will have the exact same state as the preceding iteration, and so you'll have an infinite loop. This can happen, as it is not guaranteed that any of the neighbors will have a cost that is less than the cost of the current state.
In general, the current position might already be on a "hill", where there is actually no direct improvement by making one move. In fact, it could even get worse by making any move. Consider this example, where the goal state is this:
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 0

... and the current state is this:
0 2 3 
4 5 6
7 1 8

Note how the values 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 are all on their final place. We "only" need to move that 1 to the top-left corner, and the gap to the bottom-right corner. The current state is on a huge hill, and the valley around it is large! So the approach you took will in general not work.

The cost calculation is a bit rudimentary:

Surely it is better if a misplaced value is close to its destination, than when it is far from it, but in both of these cases your cost will contribute 0 for this particular value. You could refine it by adding the (Manhattan) distance that each value has to its destination.
The distance that the value 0 (the gap) has to its destination, or even its correct positioning, is of little importance. As this gap needs to (necessarily) move around as you play moves, you should exclude it from the cost calculation.


There is no protection from running in cycles. Implement a notion of visited states and avoid playing moves that lead to already visited positions. For implementing this, you need a key for each state. To achieve that, it will be handy to not represent the state as a 3x3 list, but as a 9-member tuple. Such a tuple can be used as a key.

Not a real issue, but it doesn't look right to hardcode the goal state inside the State constructor. Also, I would define the goal state as an instance of State. It should be defined only once -- not each time a State instance is created. I suggest making it a class member. (An alternative would be that you pass it as argument to hill_climbing)


If we want to stick with the principle of hillclimbing, you'll need to foresee making several moves in a row in order to reach a state that improves on the cost of the current state. You could first look at the direct neighbors, but if none of them improve the cost, then look at the neighbors of the neighbors, and then the neighbors of those, ...etc, until you find a state that is an improvement (a "climb").
Here is a modification of your code, with the above remarks implemented:
class State:
    goal_state: 'State | None' = None
    
    def __init__(self, state, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.state = tuple(state)  # Use tuple representation to use it as key
        self.cost = self.calculate_cost()

    @staticmethod
    def distance(a, b):
        return abs(a // 3 - b // 3) + abs(a % 3 - b % 3)
    
    def calculate_cost(self):
        if not self.goal_state:
            return 0
        return sum(self.distance(self.state.index(val), i)
                   for i, val in enumerate(self.goal_state.state))

    # Create a nice representation 
    def __repr__(self):
        s = " ".join(map(str, self.state)).replace("0", ".")
        return s[:5] + "\n" + s[6:11] + "\n" + s[12:]

    # Helper function to create a neighbor state
    def swap(self, a, b):
        ab = a + b
        return State(tuple(self.state[ab - i if i in (a, b) else i] 
                           for i in range(9)), self)

    # A generator: leave it for the caller to make this into a list
    def generate_neighbors(self):
        gap = self.state.index(0)
        if gap < 6:     # move down
            yield self.swap(gap, gap + 3)
        if gap > 2:     # move up
            yield self.swap(gap, gap - 3)
        if gap % 3 < 2: # move right
            yield self.swap(gap, gap + 1)
        if gap % 3 > 0: # move left
            yield self.swap(gap, gap - 1)

    # hash/__eq__ implementations to use the state field as key
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.state)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.state == other.state

def hill_climbing(current_state):
    path = [current_state]
    while current_state.cost > 0:
        visited = set([current_state])  # Avoid running in cycles
        # Start a BFS
        queue = list(current_state.generate_neighbors())
        for neighbor in queue:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                if neighbor.cost < current_state.cost:
                    break  # We have an improvement!
                queue.extend(neighbor.generate_neighbors())
        # Flush the path we found into a list
        subpath = []
        while neighbor != current_state:
            subpath.append(neighbor)
            neighbor = neighbor.parent
        # Extend the overall path with this subpath
        path += reversed(subpath)
        current_state = path[-1]

    return path

Here is how you would run it with the example configuration you gave in the question:
State.goal_state = State((1, 2, 3, 8, 0, 4, 7, 6, 5))
start = State((2, 0, 3, 1, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5))
path = hill_climbing(start)
# Print the solution path
for state in path:
    print("-----")
    print(state)

This will output:
-----
2 . 3
1 8 4
7 6 5
-----
. 2 3
1 8 4
7 6 5
-----
1 2 3
. 8 4
7 6 5
-----
1 2 3
8 . 4
7 6 5

On a final note: the A* algorithm is a better choice here than hill climbing.
